# Mostrar Page vindo do SpringBoot no angular 6 usando Angular Material Data Table

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-material

Olá, estou iniciando em angular e gostaria de mostrar o resultado de uma pesquisa que está vindo de uma api que construi usando springboot.
minha response esta vindo assim:

```
{,…}
content: [{id: 33, dsProjeto: "teste", nomeProjeto: "nometeste", setor: "Insurance",…},…]
0: {id: 33, dsProjeto: "teste2", nomeProjeto: "nometeste2", setor: "Insurance",…}
1: {id: 36, dsProjeto: "teste3", nomeProjeto: "nometeste3",…}
2: {id: 37, dsProjeto: "teste4", nomeProjeto: "nometeste4",…}
3: {id: 38, dsProjeto: "teste5", nomeProjeto: "nometeste5", setor: "Industry",…}
empty: false
first: true
last: true
number: 0
numberOfElements: 4
pageable: "INSTANCE"
size: 0
sort: {sorted: false, unsorted: true, empty: true}
totalElements: 4
totalPages: 1
```

A api tá retornando uma Page, o problema é que preciso mostrar isso no front e não sei direito como faz. Segui alguns tutorias, mas não está funcionando. Aparece o seguinte erro no console: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined. E realmente, quando dou um console.log em data no onInit do atestado.component, apos o subscribe, data aparece como undefined. Porém, como disse acima o meu serviço tá retornando o response certo. Na aba network do crome, o response vem certinho. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Seguem meus códigos do angular:

atestado.component.html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
<!-- Id Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="dsProjeto">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> DsProjeto </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dsProjeto}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="nomeGerente">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nome Gerente </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nomeGerente}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

atestado.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { ProjetoService } from 'src/app/shared/services/projeto.service';
import { Atestado, Page } from './atestado';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-atestado',
   templateUrl: './atestado.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./atestado.component.scss']
 })
 export class AtestadoComponent implements OnInit {

 dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Atestado>;
 displayedColumns= ['id', 'dsProjeto', 'nomeGerente'];
 page: Page;

 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;   

 constructor(private projetoService: ProjetoService) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projetoService.buscaAtestados('java',1,'id','ASC')
    .subscribe(
        data  => {
            console.log(data);
            this.page = data;
            const atestados = data.content;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Atestado>(atestados);
        });
 }
}
```

projeto.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { mappingUrls } from src/app/shared/commons/constants/constants.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { GenericService } from './generic.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjetoService {
   private applicationUrl = 'http://' + environment.host + ':' + environment.port + '/api/';

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private genericService: GenericService) {}

 public buscaAtestados(filtro,page,size): Observable<Page> {

return  this.httpClient.get<Atestado>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscaAtestados, { 
    params: new  HttpParams ()
        .set('filtro',filtro)
        .set('page',page.toString())
        .set('size',size.toString())
}).pipe(
        map(res =>  res["payload"])
    );
}
```

a interface atestado.ts

```
export interface Page {
  content: Atestado[];
  pageable: string;
  totalElements: number;
  last: boolean;
  totalPages: number;
  size: number;
  number: number;
  sort: Sort;
  numberOfElements: number;
  first: boolean;
  empty: boolean;
}

export interface Sort {
  sorted: boolean;
  unsorted: boolean;
  empty: boolean;
}

export interface Atestado {
  id: string;
  dsProjeto: string;
  setor: string;
  un: string;
  dtInicio: string;
  //codigo omitido
}
```

Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linhas que você quer mostrar estão no `content` do objeto da resposta. Você precisa ler isso da forma correta. Sugiro que você crie uma classe a partir do `JSON` da resposta, do `JSON` todo, pois você vai precisar disso depois para fazer a paginação. Este artigo que você usou é uma ótima referência.

Para criar o `JSON`, se estiver usando o [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), use o plugin [JSONToTS](http://www.jsontots.com/) `JSONToTS`. Então no `GET`, faça o retorno tipado:

```
public buscaAtestados(filtro,page,size): Observable<any[]> {

return  this.httpClient.get<IResult>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscaAtestados, { 
    params: new  HttpParams ()
        .set('filtro',filtro)
        .set('page',page.toString())
        .set('size',size.toString())
}).pipe(
        map(res =>  res["payload"])
    );
}
```

Na sua `dataSource`, pegue apenas o content para os dados:

```
this.projetoService.buscaAtestados(filter, pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])),
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
    )
    .subscribe( (atestados: IResult) => this.atestadoSubject.next(atestados.content));
```

**EDITADA**

Sua classe como JSON ficaria assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: oi, obrigada pela resposta! Não sei se entendi bem o que vc quis dizer sobre criar uma classe a partir do json. Eu não estou usando vscode... mas, pelo o que entendi, seria pra eu criar uma classe com os atributos qu evem no meu json? Bem, foi isso que eu fiz, e postei as alterações, criei uma interface atestado.ts. Porém, no meu datasource, na parte de pegar o content, ele não reconhece o .content como um metodo e nem chega a compilar. Desculpa se entendi errado o que vc quis dizer.

Comment: Sua interface ficou incompleta, adicionei um print de como ficaria a partir do `JSON` que você forneceu na sua pergunta. Observe que ela tem a propriedade `Content`, um array, que eu entendi como sendo os dados que você quer exibir no `data-tabl`e.

Comment: Olá! Obrigada pela ajuda de novo!  dei uma modificada na minha interface. usei a versão web do Jsont o ts. Também  mudei algumas coisas no meu service que passou a retornar um Observable<Page> e tambem  fiz modificações do meu datasource. Mas mesmo assim, não está mostrando nada.. tem idéia do que seja? Acredito que meu datasource esteja errado agora, mas não sei onde.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, como estou devolvendo um Page da minha Api, o observable tinha que ser do tipo Page .. O erro estava no meu serviço.
Segue código corrigido:

```
 public buscaAtestados( 
            filtro: string,
            page: number,
            ord:string,
            dir:string): Observable<Page> {

    return  this.httpClient
    .get<Page>(this.applicationUrl + mappingUrls.projetoService.buscaAtestados, { 
    params: new  HttpParams ()
        .set('filtro',filtro)
        .set('pag',page.toString())
        .set('ord',ord)
        .set('dir', dir)
    }).pipe(
        map(res => {
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```